# How to deserialize a general tree into a vector?

Tags: c++, tree, deserialization

I’ve serialized a tree into a file (myFile.txt), in which each node is actually a separate `\n` terminated line:

Root
Node 00
Node 000
|
Node 001
|
|
Node 01
Node 010
|
Node 011
Node 0110
Node 01100
|
|
|
|
Node 02
Node 020
Node 0200
|
Node 0201
|
|
|
|

It can be deserialized into an array of predefined depth with the following:

```
#include <afx.h>
#include <memory>

using std::unique_ptr;

// A node of an N-ary tree 
struct Node {
    CString key;
    unique_ptr<Node> child[N];  // Array of pointers for N children 
};

// Utility function to create a new N-ary tree node 
unique_ptr<Node> newNode(CString key)
{
    unique_ptr<Node> temp = std::make_unique<Node>();
    temp->key = key;
    return temp;
}
int deSerialize(unique_ptr<Node>& root, CStdioFile* pfr)
{
    // Read next item from file.   
    CString fs;
    pfr->ReadString(fs);

    // If no more items or next item is marker, return 1 to indicate same
    if (fs == "" || fs == "|") { return 1; }
    // else create new node and recurse for all its children
    root = newNode(fs);
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) // cond-expression omitted, break governs exit
        if (deSerialize(root->child[i], pfr))
            break;

    // Finally return 0 for successful finish
    return 0;   
}
int main()
{
    FILE* f;
    errno_t err = _tfopen_s(&f, _T("myFile.txt"), _T("rt, ccs = UTF-16LE"));
    if (err != NULL) { TRACE("Could not open file"); return 0; }
    CStdioFile fr(f);
    CStdioFile* pfr = &fr;

    unique_ptr<Node> root1 = NULL;
    deSerialize(root1, pfr);

    fr.Close();

}
```

But when I try to change from using an array to a vector, the first time it tries to recurse at the `if` statement, the `deSerialize` function throws an exception because the vector subscript is out of range.

```
#include <afx.h>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::unique_ptr;

// A node of a general tree 
struct Node {
    CString key;
    vector<unique_ptr<Node>> child;  // A vector of pointers for children 
};
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

> [...] throws an exception because the vector subscript is out of range.

You want to construct your `vector` for `N` children:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Node>> child(N);
```

will construct a `vector` of size `N` containing `N` default constructed `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Thanks, but Compiler won't let me do that unless I specify a value for N, and I don't want to do that.  I'm trying to find a solution for a general tree, not an N-ary tree.  I believe the problem is because the first children of the root node are constructed with a different syntax than subsequent children.  E.g. if it was being done with literals, it would go
`std::unique_ptr<Node> root = newNode( _T("Root") );
(root->child).push_back(newNode("Node 00"));
(root->child[0]->child).push_back(newNode("Node 000"));
(root->child[0]->child[0]->child).push_back(newNode("Node 0000"));`
etc.

Comment: Another way of putting this is that the first time the `deSerialize` function arrives at the `if()` statement, i = 0 so why would the vector subscript be out of range? The struct should have root1 [ptr], [ptr] expands to (key (“Root”), child) and child should expand to [0] key (“Node00”), [1] (key (“Node01”), etc. Seems like the first child of root1 should be child[0], with value “Node00”. Why should you have to pre-dimension the vector to get that?

Comment: I guess technically my question was answered, although pre-dimensioning the vector so that it simply imitates an array wasn't the kind of answer I was looking for. I thought that in principle using a vector would be preferable because vectors support dynamic resizing. In my first comment above, the tree was created without requiring a pre-dimensioned vector, and the serialized tree contains the same information so it ought to also be capable of re-creation without pre-dimensioning. I guess I'll re-post the question but state that it has to be done without specifying an N value?